# DNS CNAME domain.tld, email address problem

Tags: dns, email, cname, email-address

After having bought a **domain** (`example.tld`) without webspace, I want to let this point to my other domain called (`myhomepage.somefreehoster.com`).

I know this will work using DNS CNAME record and when someone looks for `example.tld`, the resulting IP will be this of `myhomepage.somefreehoster.com`.

However, how do I let this pass for emails sent via domain `@example.tld` (like `webmaster@example.tld`)?
I do not want to send my mail through `myhomepage.somefreehoster.com`.

If this is not possible the way I am trying to do, let me please know some clever alternatives.
Still, preferably, I would like to use a DNS redirect.

Comment: for email you set different type of DNS record (MX), so it can differ from main DNS records.

Comment: finally, I found out the domain provider only allows A records (I guess CNAME is for subdomains only), so everything is working now correctly; just had to adapt the .htaccess file;
domains has to be told to hosting site too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a mail server wants to deliver mail to `@domain.tld`, it makes a DNS lookup for the `MX` record for that particular domain. It will connect to the server returned by the lookup with SMTP, and send the e-mail.

So, you should add the `MX` record for your `@domain.tld` domain, and enter the name of the server that handles the e-mail for that domain.

Comment: I try to let emails pass through using '@domain.tld' without changing anything because this is already working fine.

Comment: `CNAME` has nothing to do with E-Mails. So, if your E-Mails for @domain.tld work fine already, you can simply add the CNAME.